# Is there an equivalent to an inner exception for iOS Objective C?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, telemetry

I want to log some non-fatal errors from my iOS app to Firebase Crashlytics. I'm getting NSError objects from the various SDKs that we're using; however, they are not terribly informative by themselves. I need to add a message to them so I can tell where in our code they were called and what happened before the error condition occurred. For our Java Android app, I can create a new Exception with an inner Exception, like so:

`new Exception("My message", originalException);`

Is there an equivalent in iOS Objective C?

Other things that could potentially solve my problem:

- I only see one `recordError` method on Crashlytics, which only takes the one argument of "error." Is there a hidden method I'm not aware of?
- I could create a new NSError object and clone everything over, prepending my new message. Is this reasonable to do? What are all the properties of the original NSError object I need to copy over to ensure I'm capturing all the important things about the original error?
- I could call Crashlytics `log` or `logWithFormat` before calling `recordError`, then anything historically I wanted to know would show up on the Log tab in Crashlytics. I'm not crazy about this, since it seems like the same error could happen at multiple points in the code and I don't necessarily want Firebase to lump those together. Is Firebase smart enough to not lump those together? Alternately, is this just *'the way things are done'* and I need to get over it and add my telemetry this way without complaint?

Thank you.

Comment: You could subclass `NSError` and in your subclass create an initialiser that accepts, say, a message and an instance of `NSError` - Then make sure your `localisedDescription` returns an appropriate string; say your message plus the `localisedDescription` of the other `NSError`

Comment: That makes sense. I'm just a little put out that there isn't anything built into the language that does that already. Thought I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you approach this problem from Crashlytics side. You need to first determine how you want to track your information, what information you are tracking and how you will be tracking it. When you have answers such as "Can Firebase lump those together?" you should dig into code and choose appropriate solution. Also using other tool than Crashlytics could potentially be a solution as well (not saying you should do that, just *could*).

I would personally go with subclassing an `NSError` object and wrapping original. You could add additional properties that could later help you in tracking information. Technically speaking your class could wrap another instance of your class that wraps a `NSError` so you could have `error->originalError->originalError` which is a good thing. Another potentially inconvenient thing that could happen is that you send your error twice or multiple times (original + wrapped) in different modules. You could also track that by having some unique identifier that is created only once.

To try and dig into some code...

```
@interface AppError: NSError

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSError *originalError;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *message;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *identifier;

@end

@implementation AppError

- (id)initWithMessage:(NSString *)message andOriginalError:(NSError *)error {
    if((self = [super initWithDomain:@"AppError" code:100 userInfo:nil])) {
        self.originalError = error;
        self.message = message;
        
        if([error isKindOfClass:[AppError class]]) {
            self.identifier = [(AppError *)error identifier];
        } else {
            self.identifier = [[NSUUID new] UUIDString];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

+ (NSError *)flatMapErrors:(NSError *)error {
    if(![error isKindOfClass:[AppError class]]) {
        return error; // Is a normal error so just return it
    }
    
    NSString *identifier = nil;
    NSMutableArray<NSString *> *messages = [[NSMutableArray<NSString *> alloc] init];
    NSError *originalError = nil;
    
    for(AppError *currentError = error; [currentError isKindOfClass:[AppError class]]; currentError = currentError.originalError) {
        identifier = currentError.identifier;
        originalError = currentError.originalError;
        [messages addObject:currentError.message];
    }
    
    NSString *message = nil;
    for(NSString *errorMessage in messages.reverseObjectEnumerator) {
        if(message == nil) {
            message = errorMessage;
        } else {
            message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", errorMessage, message];
        }
    }
    
    return [NSError errorWithDomain:@"AppError.flatMapErrors" code:originalError.code userInfo:@{@"message": message, @"original_error": originalError, @"error_id": identifier}];
}

@end

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Case 1
    AppError *err = [[AppError alloc] initWithMessage:@"Test" andOriginalError:[NSError errorWithDomain:@"testCase1" code:500 userInfo:@{@"dev_message": @"something bad happened"}]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [AppError flatMapErrors:err]);
    // Case 2
    NSLog(@"%@", [AppError flatMapErrors:[self scenarioA]]);
}

- (NSError *)scenarioA {
    return [[AppError alloc] initWithMessage:@"Scenario A occurred" andOriginalError:[self scenarioB]];
}

- (NSError *)scenarioB {
    return [[AppError alloc] initWithMessage:@"Scenario B occurred" andOriginalError:[self scenarioC]];
}

- (NSError *)scenarioC {
    return [[AppError alloc] initWithMessage:@"Scenario C occurred" andOriginalError:[NSError errorWithDomain:@"testCase2" code:500 userInfo:@{@"dev_message": @"something bad happened"}]];
}



@end
```

(apologies for being a bit rusty with ObjectiveC)

You could change the interface your error class implementation anyway you see fit. But mostly this approach can pack together any number of errors you want which is demonstrated in second case. The result prints

```
Error Domain=AppError.flatMapErrors
Code=500 "(null)" 
UserInfo = { 
    message = Scenario A occurred (Scenario B occurred (Scenario C occurred)),          
    original_error=Error Domain=testCase2 Code=500 "(null)" UserInfo={dev_message=something bad happened}, 
    error_id=447149A0-F770-4F1F-90CA-0E7BF8967B1C
}
```

This way you get all the info you need to push to any service like Crahlytics. From your code side you always need to use `flatMapErrors` which is able to resolve for both `AppError` and `NSError` which is pretty convenient. So you don't need to change interface anywhere. Note that methods `scenarioN` return plain `NSError` and not `AppError`.

Also adding a unique identifier will help you identify if an error has been sent multiple times. Imagine that methods `scenarioB` and `scenarioC` would both send an error to Crashlytics. The error would look different but would essentially be the same error. You would be able to see that in Crashlytics as you would see 2 errors with same identifier.

Code needs some improvements but I believe it should be enough to illustrate the features. Hope it gets you closer to your solution.